# Pass SSRS parameters into Drill through report VIA url

Tags: url, reporting-services, parameter-passing, ssrs-2012, drillthrough

Im having trouble passing multiple parameters to my drill though report using an url.

I have got a single one working however when i try to add the next one it doesn't like what i have put.

```
 ="http://rpt.Test.local/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2f%5bQuote+Tool%5d%2fChange%20Elec%20Split&PC="&Parameters!PC.Value
```

Above is the working one parameter and im now trying to add 
        MTC = Parameters!MTC.Value.

Just think im imputting wrong.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.. almost there but just a small tweek:

```
="http://rpt.Test.local/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2f%5bQuote+Tool%5d%2fChange%20Elec%20Split&"&PC=" &Parameters!PC.Value &"&MTC=" & Parameters!MTC.Value & "&rs:Command=Render"
```